# Incrementing an Iterator with and without creating a template

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, increment

I'm writing a very simple line of code to display the contents of a map container and I came across an interesting error.
If I write:

```
    void DisplayMap(const map<int, string>&  myMap)
{
    for (const map<int, string>::const_iterator myIterator = myMap.begin(); 
         myIterator != myMap.end(); ++myIterator)
    {
        cout << myIterator->first << ": " << myIterator->second << endl;
    }   
}
```

The compiler has objection to my use of `++myIterator`, claiming this function has no overloaded operator of type '++'.  But, if I make this a Template:

```
template <typename T>
void DisplayMap(const T&  myMap)
{
    for (map<int, string>::const_iterator myIterator = myMap.begin(); myIterator != myMap.end(); ++myIterator)
    {
        cout << myIterator->first << ": " << myIterator->second << endl;    
    }
}
```

Then there is no issue.  The code runs perfectly.  I was hoping someone could explain why the compiler has no issue here.  As I understand it, making the function a template is akin to invoking auto for a variable type.  But what exactly is the compiler doing?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You made your iterator const here `const map<int, string>::const_iterator myIterator ` therefore you cannot mutate the iterator itself, which includes incrementing it. Drop that first `const`. Notice your second version doesn't have the leading `const` which is why it works, has nothing to do with templates here.

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks for pointing it out.  Should have seen that.  The red print from my facepalm should last a bit . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the iterator and template stuff is not that relevant here. What is relevant is the `const`:

```
    for (const map<int, string>::const_iterator myIterator = myMap.begin(); 
               myIterator != myMap.end(); ++myIterator)
          ^^ !!!
```

You cannot increment a `const iterator` because it is `const`. You would get similar error for

```
for (const int i= 0; i< N; ++i) {
```

Here, `i` cannot be incremented because it is `const`.

In your template version you dropped the `const`, thats why there is no error.

Comment: This facepalm moment brought to you by yours truly.  Thanks for pointing it out @idclev

Comment: @BrandonThompson making such a mistake is no shame, but ignoring the compiler error message is. Compiler errors are your friends. I mean I can only see that you didnt include it in the question, but in fact it would have been all that is needed to answer it. Incrementing is an obvious case but in general I don't remember for all methods if they are `const` or not, and I don't have to because the compiler will tell me